# ASP.Net project website location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I just created a Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC razor project, built and ran.  The website showed up in my browser at

```
localhost:49577
```

The localhost part is expected.  But what is the 49577?  How did it decide to put it there?  Can I change it?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change port in visual studio, I don't know your VS studio version.

For 2012 version of VS:

Right click on a project -> choose **Properties** -> Choose **Web** tab -> edit **Project Url**

or

read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using VS 2012 with IIS, which I did manage to configure correctly to allow it to run.  But everything under properties is grayed out.  I can't change it.

Comment: Have you verified if is checked **Use local IIS Web Server** option ?

Comment: Is your application running on Debug mode? If so then stop debugging and then set the port number.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [port number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29).

Visual Studio picks a random port for each project; you can change it in Project Properties.

Answer (score 1):

That is the port number. It is auto assigned by visual studio development server.

If you right click the project name in the solution explorer and go to web, you can choose to auto assign this port, or set a specific port number.

You can also choose to use your local machines IIS, but you will need administrator priviledges.

Answer (score 1):

The number that you are referring to is the **Port Number** for your project(Web Application) that is randomly generated when you start your project.This helps IIS Express or Local Development Server listen to your request.

You can change it manually. See [Specify a Port for the Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For VS2010 it is:
Right Click On Project -> Properties->Web->Servers->Specific Port